# jQuery UI datepicker not triggering a change in extjs field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, extjs

I have a form that has two fields, a "start" date, and an "end" date. I have to use the jQuery UI datepicker because I this application will be run on a 7" touchscreen, and I needed to customize the size of the calendar popped up by the datepicker. The problem that I'm facing is that when I select a date, it is not triggering a "change" event in the field, and therefore the graph below isn't changing. If I physically type in the date, everything works as intended. What event should I look for in my code to trigger the chart below the date fields?

[image: Example]

Comment: I strongly believe this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your intended question was "How can I customize the size of an ExtJS date picker" or "How can I write my own date picker". [As an example, let me show you the custom date picker I made.](https://i.imgur.com/8mbPsJQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are applying the date of the datepicker to a `Ext.form.field.Textfield`.
Have a look at the [checkChange-config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-checkChangeEvents) from the ExtJs 6.2.1 docs:

> A list of event names that will be listened for on the field's input
>   element, which will cause the field's value to be checked for changes.
>   If a change is detected, the change event will be fired, followed by
>   validation if the validateOnChange option is enabled. Defaults to
>   ['change', 'propertychange', 'keyup'] in Internet Explorer, and
>   ['change', 'input', 'textInput', 'keyup', 'dragdrop'] in other
>   browsers.
>   ...
>   If you need
>   to guarantee on-the-fly change notifications including these edge
>   cases, you can call the checkChange method on a repeating interval,
>   e.g. using Ext.TaskManager, or if the field is within a
>   Ext.form.Panel, you can use the FormPanel's
>   Ext.form.Panel#pollForChanges configuration to set up such a task
>   automatically.
>   ...

So you may tweak the list there to fit your needs or try the workaround with `Ext.TaskManager`.

Comment: Silly question, but does this work in the "Modern" toolkit as well? I know that Sencha decided to cobble together their ExtJS and Sencha Touch packages to one somewhat obviously cobbled package.